# getting "too much recurions" when validating js via regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to validate a username with RegEx in Javascript and while the result of `.test` is true all works fine, but (somtimes) when  i use a string that doesnt match, my app breaks and i get the error ***Too much recursion***. I want to know where in my RegEx (Or code) have i gone wrong to cause such a thing.

This is my code (RegEx):

```js
console.log(/^[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]([ _]?[A-Za-z0-9À-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]+)+$/g.test("RegExr was created by gskinner_com_and is proudly  hosted by Media Temple"));
```

I want the correct string to start with a letter, then have any combination of letters and digits with spaces and underscores allowed between them but only one at a time.

The regex works in websites related to testing it, and on my own code, and i get the error when the invalid input is far from the beginning of the string, in fact my computer takes longer to calculate the result the further i put the error (Lets say a dot or 2 spaces after each other) till on a certain point i get the error.
or the use of too many characters like
What is the problem? position of the `$` or the use of too many characters like `À-ÖØ-öø-ÿ`? and what can i do to fix it ?

Comment: The catastrophic backtracking is due to the nested quantifiers in the group. Perhaps you can make the character class inside the group not optional, and optionally repeat the character class after matching the first character. `^[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ][A-Za-z0-9À-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]*(?:[ _][A-Za-z0-9À-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]+)+$` https://regex101.com/r/vighbB/1

Comment: I tried this and works totally fine. ^, cant flag it as answer unfortunately

Comment: I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The catastrophic backtracking is due to the nested quantifiers in the group. If the pattern can not match, the nested quantifiers allow a lot of positions to backtrack to, still trying to get a match.

You could start the pattern matching a single char, and then optionally match one of the character class `[A-Za-z0-9À-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]*`

Then in the repeating group, match either a space or underscore `[ _]` followed by 1 or more times the already existing character class `[A-Za-z0-9À-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]+`

This does not disable the backtracking, it takes out a nested quantifier to allow for less positions to backtrack to.

Note that repeating a capture group, captures the value of the last iteration. If you don't need the capture group value afterwards, you can make it a non capture group using `(?:` instead.

```
^[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ][A-Za-z0-9À-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]*(?:[ _][A-Za-z0-9À-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]+)+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DtfORD/1)

To also match a single word you can make the quantifier `*` for the group to match zero or more times:

```
^[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ][A-Za-z0-9À-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]*([ _][A-Za-z0-9À-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uhQwzQ/1)

Comment: Ive tried something different, what about this:
`/^[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ][A-Za-z0-9À-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]*([ _][A-Za-z0-9À-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]+)*$/g`

Comment: @CaliphHamid You can also do that, then the part that matches a space or hyphen is optional. See https://regex101.com/r/uhQwzQ/1